# Credentials required for listing services for a remote computer via WMI?

Tags: .net, wmi

Are administrator credentials (for that remote machine) required to view the services of a remote computer?

I don't know much about WMI and I imagine it would be required, but I would love to see an official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspect, the remote user's account must be a member of the Administrators group on the local machine.  More information is available here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You also need to ensure that your user is not restricted using the WMI Security Control Panel. Go to Computer Management -> Services and Applications and Right Click on WMI Control and Choose Properties, then select the Security tab.

Most Windows properties (like Services) are in the root\CIMV2 namespace, so ensure that your user has access there. Administrators generally do, and if your user is not an administrator, you can grant them rights on that WMI namespace through this dialog.